# How to increment cell range by a specific number [Excel]

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to change the range of cells by 4, the default behavior changes the cell by one starting from the first selected cell. I have this:

[image]

If I try to spread the function on another cell I get this increment by 1:

[image]

I want the range from 45 to 49.

I have Excel 2016.

Comment: Use the `INDIRECT` function and the data in your K column (desired row #s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:
`=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,ROW(A40)-ROW(A1)+(ROW(A1)-1)*5,0,5))`
and you can drag it down
every time you go down one Row the formula will move 5 rows
Offset will choose the five cell to Sum

Answer (score 2):

I prefer sumifs. I would convert the ranges column to two separate columns a lower and an upper and populate {40,44;45;49;50,54;etc}. then the formula in occurrence would look like this:

=SUMIFS(H:H,F:F,">="&J3,F:F,"<"&K4,G:G,L3)